# Remove all newlines from String but keep ONE newline after dot (.)

Tags: java, string, newline

I have this input String (containg linebreaks):

```
That is
a test.
seems to work pretty good? working. Another test again.
```

And I want to reach this state:

```
That is a test.
seems to work pretty good? working. Another test again.
```

Any ideas?

i 'm trying this:

```
replaceAll("[^\\.]\\n", "");
```

Comment: A regex might help you. Apart from that any attempts from your side ?

Comment: What code have you got so far? What is happening that you are not expecting?

Comment: replaceAll("^\\s+|\\s+$|\\s*(\n)\\s*|(\\s)\\s*", "$1$2");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)). This will see if there is a non-dot character without actually replacing that character (and thus deleting part of the last word). Also, you should replace the newline with a space so that the words are not joined.

```
text.replaceAll("(?<=[^\\.])\\n", " ")
```

Or, you can capture the non-dot character in a group and re-insert it in the replacement:

```
text.replaceAll("([^\\.])\\n", "$1 ")
```

Both will give you

```
That is a test.
seems to work pretty good? working. Another test again.
```